# windows 2008 R2 IIS 7.5 server stalling while serving web pages

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I have an issue where my server doesn't serve up pages on the initial request.  I have to F5 (refresh) the page serveral times before the page actually gets served.  This issue is on the server itself (not network related) because if I browse to the sites by their IP from the server, I'm seeing the same problem.  There's nothing in the event logs that looks abnormal.  I've tried iisreset and rebooted the maching, still seeing the same issue.  This server has been online and serving pages for over a year now and this just started yesterday.

I'm really not sure where to start digging to resolve this?  I also did a windows update yesterday, a virus scan and disk defrag, nothing resolved it.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by putting up a basic HTML and ASP(x) page to see if it's an IIS issue, or something application specific.  If the HTML/ASP pages work fine, then troubleshoot your specific application.  Otherwise, browse the site from the server itself to rule out network issues.  If that still doesn't work, maybe check DNS or other programs running on the system.

Comment: as I said in my OP, I've already tried browsing to the sites themselves from the server directly and am seeing the same behavior.  It doesn't matter if it's an html page or an aspx page, I'm seeing the same thing.  Sometimes they load right up, others I have to refresh the page 2-10 times before it will load.

Comment: In that case i would test via telnet to see where the delay is happening.  You can also disable extra ISAPI modules to rule out them interfering.  I've seen this kind of stuff happen before when servers are configured with improper dns settings, causing slow reverse lookups on the client IPs.

Answer (score 0):

I would enable failed request tracing.

- Open IIS Manager
- Select a site and enable "Failed request tracing" from the actions on the right.
- Then in the IIS section of the site, open 'Failed Request Tracing rules'
- Add a new rule for 'All content', Status code: 200, all providers.
- Hit the site in a browser,
- Open C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVCx\ where x is the id of the site
- Open the latest *.xml file in a browser, IE on a server usually doesn't work.
  I would copy the file and the freb.xsl to a workstation and open it there.
- Under 'Request details' you may be able to see what took so long.

Comment: Of course as soon as I set this up, I'm not seeing loading issues.  I'll keep it up though and keep pressing it and report back when I have something.

Comment: ok got it fail and have an xml log...what am I looking for in here?  I don't have a request details section...

Comment: You should not look at the raw XML. View the file in a browser where the xsl has transformed the XML into nice Html. On Windows 7 a double-click on the xml file should open IE. If not, start IE and open the xml file manually.

Comment: well the server just miraculously started working normally again this morning.  I marked your answer as the answer though because I think this would have lead me down the right path and I will keep it in my back pocket in case it happens again.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: ok, the problem is back.  It doesn't log anything when the request fails.  I've changed it to log all response codes (100-999) and it still doesn't log anything when the request fails.  Any ideas?

Comment: is there some kind of an IIS debugger that I can attach to determine what is causing it to fail?