# web sites leaking memory? IIS 7.5 Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, memory-usage, memory-leak

I have several web sites on my windows 2008 server that have been working flawlessly for over a year.  Just a few days ago I ran into an issue where my server stopped serving up pages on some of these sites for no apparent reason.  I dug into it a little more today and I see that some of my sites (they're all asp.net mvc 3.0 sites), are consuming over 460MB of memory.  Like I said, this just started the other day after a very long period of time of no issues at all.

I have two questions:
1) is there a way to throttle how much memory is consumed by the w3wp process before I can force it to restart (restart the app pool for a particular site) so that it doesn't keep hogging all of the memory?
2) any ideas what could have caused this to start happening?

Comment: TomTom posted what the answer is more than likely is. I would follow that path of troublesooting.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) is there a way to throttle how much memory is consumed by the w3wp process before I can force 
>   it to restart

No, and it makes no sense because - the apps live in their own processes.

> 2) any ideas what could have caused this to start happening?

Yes. Bad code. That it as good as it gets without attaching a Debugger. THAT SIAD: 460mbis not exactly a lot of Memory. Can be some bad Caching.

Comment: ok it turns out it might not be a memory issue.  I just did an iisreset an cleared up a ton of memory but still seeing the same issue where IIS does not serve pages on some initial page requests.  I have to refresh the page several times to get it to load.  I'm pulling my hair out here.  I have no idea what's causing this or why it started or worst of all...how to fix it.  Here is the other thread I started yesterday about this issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/442777/windows-2008-r2-iis-7-5-server-stalling-while-serving-web-pages